# Error when creating button cakephp An Internal Error Has Occurred Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred

Tags: cakephp

```
<?= $this->Form->button($this->Assets->image('right-arrow.png'), [
    'class' => 'btn-captcha',
    'id' => 'invisibleCaptchaShort'
]); ?>
```

No error on this action but when i try to create a button with text like this

```
<?= $this->Form->button('short'), [
    'class' => 'btn-captcha',
    'id' => 'invisibleCaptchaShort'
]); ?>
```

Showing : An Internal Error Has Occurred
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
can someone please solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you receive an error, make sure to check your logs (`/logs/` folder), and/or to enable debug mode (`debug` option in `config/app.php` or `config/app_local.php`) to get more information on the error that occurred.

Also it is advised to use an IDE/Editor with proper syntax highlighting, your second second example clearly has a syntax error, you're closing off the `button()` method call before the array that you want to pass as the second argument. A good IDE/Editor would highlight that there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
<?= $this->Form->button('short'), [
    'class' => 'btn-captcha',
    'id' => 'invisibleCaptchaShort'
]); ?>
```

by

```
<?= $this->Form->button('short', [
'class' => 'btn-captcha',
'id' => 'invisibleCaptchaShort'
]); ?>
```